# Firebase Search-Nested object searching in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search by string value of the child "title" from all the "category" child:

[database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7zG.png)

I've add database rules like this:

[database rules snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrNhr.png)

I tried with this code:

```
public void getData(String search_key) {
    dbref.child("data").orderByChild("title").startAt(search_key).endAt(search_key + "\uf8ff").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String title = null;
            for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataCategory:data.getChildren()) {
                    try {
                        Object object = dataCategory.child(DBConstants.CHILD_TITLE).getValue();
                        if (object != null) title = object.toString();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        //comments
                    }
                    System.out.println(title);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can achieve this using your database structure since between your `data` node and the objects that contain the `title` property there is one more child, the `Category`.

You can use the following query:

```
dbref.child("data").child("Category1")
    .orderByChild("title")
    .startAt(search_key)
    .endAt(search_key + "\uf8ff")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

And loop **only once**, not twice as you do in your code right now but you'll be able to get only the titles that exist within the `Category1` node. If you want to get all titles you should restructure your database by ading the category as a property of your objects and then simply use:

```
dbref.child("data") //No Category1 child
    .orderByChild("title")
    .startAt(search_key)
    .endAt(search_key + "\uf8ff")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

In this way you'll a have level less and this query will work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you. I've got the idea.